error reading file for hashing: No such file or directory (-1)
I'm going to create a file folder in my iOS application project in Xcode that uses local git and remote git(GitHub) for source control, but when I do File > New > Group or click one file with two fingers to create new file folder, it shows: error reading file for hashing: No such file or directory (-1),
The detail message is:
An unknown error occurred.
Domain: com.apple.dt.SourceControlErrorDomain
Code: -1
Recovery Suggestion: error reading file for hashing: No such file or directory (-1)
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-06-14 14:44:27 +0000";
    "com.apple.dt.sourcecontrol.UnderlyingErrorString" = "error reading file for hashing: No such file or directory (-1)";
}

And the images are how the error appears:
First, I create a folder.
Creating folder
Then, rename it to "MyFolder".
Rename
After it(even though I don't rename it, the error still appears), it show a block like this:
Error block
As you can see, the folder its's change it's name and it is still named as default "New Group".
doesn't change name.
I want to ask why it shows this error and how to solve it. Thanks.
